# Xcode crashes on scrolling up in a source file (13 & 14)

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ide

I encounter this behavior many times a week.
If I try to scroll up in a source file (different files over the time) Xcode shows the beach ball of death until I force quit it.

**I check the following:**

- It seems only to happen in Xcode files and not in Objc but it could be a false friend
- Xcode 13 and Xcode 14 beta 1-4
- Independent of UIKit or SwiftUI files
- There is enough memory
- No build phases are running during the crashes
- The app is not running
- The files are not in syncing folders like Dropbox or iCloud Drive

Do you also experience this behavior? Do you have any idea how to fix it? I lose a lot of time ...

Comment: Storyboard or xib ? Also in swift files ? Do you have live previews in SwiftUI ?

Comment: Hi, "only" in Swift files. UIKit and SwiftUI once :)

Comment: me too, just scroll up on swift file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73705430/2185588

Comment: @GIJoeCodes I checked it, bit is also happens in files where I do not have multiple section that are "stacked".

Answer (score 2):

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73705430/2185588) by [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum). This issue seems to be related to displaying code structure at the top. Go to **Xcode** > **Settings** > **Text Editing** and deselect "***Code structure when scrolling***". Mine hasn't crashed since.