# How to disable sticky headers in Xcode14

Tags: xcode, xcode14

In the Xcode 14 version there are these sticky headers that show where we are in the current flow of code, they cover up to 3 lines, my problem is my entire top of editor is now covered with 3 lines of Xcode menu and other 3 lines of these sticky headers, is there a way to try and turn them off in Xcode 14, they seem to cover almost 20% of screen area on my 13 inch device also they seem to hide the relevant code I am currently typing .. thanks

[image]

Comment: Goto: `Xcode` > `Preferences `>  `Text Editing` ,  and under the "display" tab. turn off `Code Structure when scrolling`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Source Editor
> New Features
> Xcode now pins elements of your code structure to the top of the editor as you scroll through a document. To toggle this behavior, use “Show: Code structure while scrolling” in Xcode’s Text Editing preferences. (10582250)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes

Go to `Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing > Display > Code Structure When Scrolling`

[image]